# How to create a getter in node add-on?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I have been in the process of writing a node add-on, and I cannot seem to figure out how add a property to a class. What I have been doing is creating a method in the `c++` add-on, and in the `javascript` I create a getter that calls the function in the add-on.

Is this the correct way to do this, or can this property be created in the `c++` add-on?

In the `c++` I do this:

```
void MyAddon::Init(Local<Object> exports, Local<Object> module) {

  // Prepare constructor template
  Local<FunctionTemplate> tpl = FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, New);
  tpl->SetClassName(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "MyAddon"));
  tpl->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);

  // Add the property
  NODE_SET_PROTOTYPE_METHOD(tpl, "currWidth", Width);


  // Export the class
  constructor.Reset(isolate, tpl->GetFunction());
  exports->Set(
      String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "MyAddon"), tpl->GetFunction());
}
```

Then in the `JavaScript` I do this:

```
const MyAddon = require('./build/Release/MyAddon')

module.exports.Addon = class Addon extends MyAddon.MyAddon {
  get width() { return this.currWidth() }
}
```

This doesn't seem like the correct way to add a property to the add-on. The [example on the website](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_object_factory) uses `NODE_SET_METHOD`, so I tried but it doesn't run the method. I don't get any errors either. The method just doesn't run...

In there example they don't try to set it on a class, which is what I am trying to do, so mine is a little different:

```
NODE_SET_METHOD((Local<Template>)tpl, "height", Height);
```

How can I create this property in the `c++`?

Comment: Regarding your nick: Please keep off mine!

Comment: You should be able to do this by using `v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor` supplying getter and setter callback functions to be invoked when corresponding object property is accessed.

Comment: Thanks VTT, could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Init` method, it was as easy as adding this line:

```
tpl->InstanceTemplate()->SetAccessor(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "width"), Width);
```

And creating a method that looks like this:

```
void MyAddon::Width(Local<String> property, const PropertyCallbackInfo<Value> &args) {}
```